# Why does my sieve not see the performance gains it should?

Tags: javascript, optimization, primes

I have created a repl.it were you can just hit run and see the difference between the sieve and non-sieve implementation of a prime finder ...

[repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/OrneryExcitingJavabytecode)

I have made all the optimizations I know of for this simple sieve and was expecting a performance gain that is higher.

Are there further optimizations I can make to the sieve to make it run faster?

Here is code:

```
/*
  PRIME 2
*/
function prime2(n){
  const primes = [2];
  not_prime: for(let i = 3; i < n; i += 2){
    for(let j = 2; j * j <= i; j++){
      if(i % j === 0){
        continue not_prime;
      }
    }
    primes.push(i);
  }
  return primes;
}

/*
  PRIME 3 - SIEVE
*/
function prime3 (n) {
  const primes = [];
  const sieve = (new Array(n)).fill(true);
  for (let i = 2; i * i <= n; i += 1) {
    if (sieve[i]) {
      for (let j = i * i; j <= n; j = j + (i * 2)) {
        sieve[j] = false;
      }
    }
  }
  makePrimes(sieve, primes, n);
  return primes;
};
function makePrimes(sieve, primes, n){
  for (let i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    if(sieve[i]) {
      primes.push(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What details do you all want?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repl.it is not a good platform for testing performance as you do not know how your code is being run on the back end.

They might be sharing your processor time with other users causing longer times to finish functions.

Try using your local machine and you should get better results.